# JavaScript: Will a = Object.assign({}, a, {k: v}) mutate a?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, side-effects, mutation

I have a object stored as key, value pairs in a url as query params. The keys of that object may change, and I want to use each of the key, value pairs in that object to update the key, value pairs of a `state` object in a redux app. I need to do so in a way that doesn't mutate the `state` object, and am currently attempting to achieve this goal as follows:

```
case 'LOAD_SEARCH_FROM_URL':
  let _state = Object.assign({}, state);
  const args = action.obj.substring(1).split('&');
  args.map((arg) => {
    const split = arg.split('=');
    _state = Object.assign({}, _state, {
      [split[0]]: JSON.parse( decodeURIComponent( split[1] ) )
    })
  })
  return _state;
```

This works fine in simple tests, but I wanted to make sure that this is not in fact performing any mutations. I'd be grateful for any insights others can offer on this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will only mutate the target (the first argument), which in your case is a newly created empty object. The sources (all subsequent arguments) will not be modified.

Comment: Amen, thanks very much @Paulpro! I realized this after posting the question, but will accept this as soon as SO lets me (they make you wait a few minutes).

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful, Object assign mutate object if they are deeply nested. And it's written in the documentation, so you should check your data structures.

> For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because
>   Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a
>   reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

If you have nested state like, { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}}, trying something like this will not be detected by redux after change:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    value: state[YOUR_REDUCER_NAME].a.b
  }
}
connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```